# Failed to execute user defined function(VectorAssembler

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I am working with a Kmeans as clustering algorithme, my code want execute and showing me this error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(VectorAssembler$$Lambda$1525/671078904: (struct<latitude:double,longitude:double>) => struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
```

here is the dataframe code:

```scala
val st = stations
    .withColumn("longitude", $"longitude".cast(sql.types.DoubleType))
    .withColumn("latitude", $"latitude".cast(sql.types.DoubleType))
val stationVA = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(Array("latitude","longitude"))
    .setOutputCol("location")
val stationWithLoc =stationVA.transform(st)

println("Assembled columns 'hour', 'mobile', 'userFeatures' to vector column 'location'")
stationWithLoc.select("name", "position").show(false)

stationWithLoc.printSchema()
stationWithLoc.show()
```

for the Schema it work but in case if I put the show I am getting the issue.

Comment: Also for me, not number values produced the problem.

Answer (score 13):

This question is old, but I just ran into this issue with `pyspark`.

I believe the error is related to null values in the data. Doing a `fillna()` on my columns before using `VectorAssembler` resolved the error.

Comment: The error isn't very explicit. Good catch ! :)

Answer (score 2):

For me, The **issue was with data**, 
I was using a csv file where it had a new line in the middle of the row. After updating.
Check the data by `df.head(1)` whether it read all the columns correctly.